# VBA to look at work allocated to staff on a particular date and put a value in another sheet against the corresponding name and date

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Not even sure what I'm trying to do is possible but there are smarter people than me out there.

I have a Master Roster which is populated for the year with staff and all the know tasks they are doing for the year (as well as leave etc.).

On a work allocation sheet, I am looking up all the names that have no work allocated to them on particular dates. I was hoping I would be able to enter values here against these names (work) and have this then transposed in the corresponding cell in the master schedule. Is this possible?

Have tried lookup formulas and scoured the net for potential code. No luck so far. Any help appreciated.

Cheers, Sandman
[Master Roster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BymDZ.png)
[Work Allocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0cim.png)

Comment: You've applied a `VBA` tag to this question, which leads the reader to assume you've dabbled in some coding, or have at least understood this will require some coding. What code have you written so far, and what about it doesn't work? If you're looking for someone here to write the code for you, that's not what we're here for. Please have a read of the help pages on Super User, and particularly https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi spikey_richie, i have dabbled in VBA. my solution wasn't very elegant however and started crashing my workbook. My code was applying a formula to all empty cells which looked up values from a secondary table I'd created. It was then pasting as values to try and keep the size and resource requirement low. Didn't work well. I can't find another method to try it. Even if there are ideas, happy to look into them myself.

Comment: "crashing my workbook" is probably because it's updating dynamically. You can stop that by using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the top of your method, and then re-enable with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` before you `end sub`.